# How to mock schema uri path in unit test case C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I've a XML validation program where I validate XML input against one XSD file placed in my solution as below:

```
public string XMLInputValidator(string xmlData, string IIP_XSDpath)
        {
            string strValidateXML = ValidateXMLInput(IIP_XSDpath, xmlData);
            string strOutputMsg;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValidateXML))
            {
                strOutputMsg = "Success Request";
            }
            else
            {
                strOutputMsg = strValidateXML;
            }
            return strOutputMsg;

        }

public static string ValidateXMLInput(string strSchemaFilePath, string xmlData)
        {
            try
            {
                string strErrorMsg = string.Empty;
                string strSoapRequest = string.Empty;
                string strFormatedXML = string.Empty;
                
                XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
                schema.Add("", HostingEnvironment.MapPath(strSchemaFilePath));
                strFormatedXML = xmlData;

                string xmlnsPattern = "\\s+xmlns\\s*(:\\w)?\\s*=\\s*\\\"(?<url>[^\\\"]*)\\\"";

                MatchCollection objMatchCol = Regex.Matches(strFormatedXML, xmlnsPattern);

                foreach (Match objMatch in objMatchCol)
                {
                    strFormatedXML = strFormatedXML.Replace(objMatch.ToString(), "");
                }
                var xmlFormatedSoapRequest = XDocument.Parse(strFormatedXML);
                xmlFormatedSoapRequest.Validate(schema, (o, e) =>
                {
                    strErrorMsg += e.Message + Environment.NewLine;

                });

                return strErrorMsg;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Calling method passes the xmlData and following XSD path:

```
const string IIP_XSDpath = @"~\XML Schema\IIPv1.0\PostUCCSchema.xsd";
ValidateXMLInput(IIP_XSDpath, xmlData)
```

This program works absolutely fine but when I run the following unit test case then I see schemaURI null exception and below is the test case:

```
public void ValidateIIPXMLInput_PostUCCValidationResult_ReturnsFalse()
        {
            MockHttpContextBase();
            const string IIP_XSDpath = @"~\XML Schema\IIPv1.0\PostUCCSchema.xsd";
            SubmitFiling submit = new SubmitFiling();
            string validationResult = submit.XMLInputValidator(xmlData, IIP_XSDpath);
            Assert.AreEqual(false, string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationResult));
        }
        public HttpContextBase MockHttpContextBase()
        {
            var moqContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            var moqRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            var moqServer = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
            moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);
            moqContext.Setup(x => x.Server.MapPath(@"~\XML Schema\IIPv1.0\PostUCCSchema.xsd")).Returns(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
            return moqContext.Object;
        }
```

following line gives exception:
"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: schemaUri"

```
schema.Add("", HostingEnvironment.MapPath(strSchemaFilePath));
```

Is there any way to resolve the above exception?